# Oracle - Check duplicates in two columns in same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to find the duplicates of two columns in the same table.

Example data set is as follows.

```
Column_1              Column_2

**15440100000220**  15440300002980

15440100000150  **15440100000220**

15440100000170  **15440300002160**

**15440300002160**  15440100006170
```

As you can see, I have duplicates in the two columns. Records in the first column are present in the second column and records in the second are present in the first.

I looked for a solution but only came across examples comparing duplicates of two tables.

Is there a way to get these duplicates into a select query? If a record in column 2 is present in column1, then that record in column 2 should be captured in the query.

Comment: And the expected result is?

Comment: Treat this table with two columns as two tables and use a simple statement with exists structure.

Comment: Hi jarlh, This is the expected result. If a record in column 2 is present in column1, then that record in column 2 should be captured into a select query.

Comment: use self join based on Column_1 = Column_2

Comment: You may looking for self join `select t1.column1 from table t1 inner join table t2 on t1.column1 =t2.column2`

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to just list the `column_2` values that also appear in `column_1` is to use `exists`:

```
select column_2
from your_table yt
where exists (
  select null
  from your_table yt2
  where yt2.column_1 = yt.column_2
);
```

I think the intent of this is clearer, but you should check the performance of the various approaches.

Answer (score 1):

you could use an having on the union subselect

```
select column_1, count(*) from (

  select column_1 as column_1
  from my_table  
  union all 
  select column_2
  from my_table  

) t 
group by column_1
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could self-join the table:

```
SELECT t1.column_1 AS col1, t1.column_2 AS col2,
       t2.column_1 AS duplicate_col1, t2.column+2 AS duplicate_col2
FROM   mytable t1
JOIN   mytable t2 ON t1.column_1 = t2.column_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want those duplicated id's? Do a self join:

```
select distinct t1.column_1
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.column_1 = t2.column_2
```